# Beginner Bottle and static files question

Tags: bottle, static-files

After using the Python http.server module I'm now trying to convert everything to Bottle and can't even get started.  My problem is locating static files - everything I've tried results in a "404" error.  So I've tried to reduce everything to the simplest possible example.  My top level directory is in "/home/dave/test" and under that is a single file (test.py), and a subdirectory ("/home/dave/test/static") containing the single file "index.html".  The html file is pretty basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bottle Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If I double click on the file itself, it opens a new browser page and displays the "Hello, World" message.  The test.py file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bottle import route, run, static_file

@route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/home/dave/test/static')

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

If I open a browser window and enter "localhost:8080/index.html" I get back the "Error: 404 Not Found" message and the terminal window where I'm running the script looks like:

```
$ ./test.py 
Bottle v0.12.16 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2019 15:31:25] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 740
```

I've tried various permutations of the URL and root parameter but nothing I've tried works.  Clearly I'm missing something very basic here.  Can somebody tell me what is wrong in in the above files (or URL)?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

I was able to contact the author of Bottle and he responded:

> a route matches against the path-part of an HTTP request URL. In your
>   example, '/static/' would match requests to
>   http://localhost:8080/static/index.html and serve 'index.html' file
>   from the '/home/dave/test/static' directory.
>   "http://localhost:8080/index.html" does not match the route you
>   specified, thus the 404 error.

I tried this and it did indeed fix the problem.